# creating a class in dreamweaver using php

Tags: php, class, dreamweaver

whenever I create a property in a class in dreamweaver it gives me an error if i don't use var which has been deprecated. Is there a way to turn this off in dreamweaver since var is no longer required?

Comment: Stop using dreamweaver - there are plenty of **really good** php IDEs. Or just email to their support about this issue ;-)

Comment: DW even is not for design less for coding, try, Komodo Edit, Eclipse, NetBeans, all free!

Comment: Or of course, you could write the class yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off dreamweaver and use an real IDE for php like eclipse!

Answer (score 0):

For light IDE:
Use Notepad++ if you are using Windows (my favorite), or TextWrangler (for Mac).

For heavy with more features:
Eclipse with php, it supports multi platform as well

Answer (score 0):

For a great IDE, you could use NuSphere. It is paid though. It has great intellisense, ftp support, database support. All in one IDE.

You could also use netbeans, which I prefer over eclipse. Just because of experience. Netbeans supports everythign you need. It is free, and I created large scale php applications with it without a problem.

Atleast check it out :)
you can also HTMl, CSS, JQuery in it etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHP Designer, i use it all the time, it even lets you setup personal libraries where you can have your own set of classes, it even supports html, javascript, css, php all in the same file depending on used tags.

i think its an awesome application and its cheap, (way cheaper then dreamweaver). And if you are willing to set it up, i has a code debug mode where you can try and go through the code. heck i even supports other languages like VBscript, Java, C#, SQL, etc on top of the standard PHP, XHTML, CSS, JS (including Jquery).

http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner.php

it comes with a 21 day trial, give it a shot.

There is also a log of details on IDEs in another post, one of them may replace the dreamweaver you are using and help you get past your issued.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166/any-good-php-ide-preferably-free-or-cheap

Comment: PS, i love the PHP IDE i use.